# Dotnetnuke - How to insert a module inside another module?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, inject

I am writing a Tabs module in which I want to be able to display other modules like html, third-party modules etc. How do I achieve that? C# code please.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mandeeps.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/live-tabs.aspx

This module is a tabs module that does just what you are looking to do. 
I don't think it's the type of thing someone can just code up for you or copy and paste it in here. You could use this module, you could buy the source of this module or you could analyze the source of DNN and figure out what really makes a module render and reproduce that.